# Cannot open csv file in jupyter, windows 10 even though the file exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I tried to open my csv files in jupyter windows 10 and it shows the error "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape". I have also went to other threads to find solution like df = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/FullData.csv') and it says file does not exist even though it exists. Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\kkang2\Desktop\FullData.csv')  #<--error here
```

Comment: Two things: 1) Is the case correct?  Win is not case sensitive but python is. 2) If correct, open Explorer > Shift right-click “copy as path”.  Paste this path into your notebook and compare for differences.

Comment: @S3DEV i replaced my original path with the one that i found using copy as path with this "\\fab2crp-nas1\home22\kkang2\Profile\Desktop\FullData.csv" and it still gives the file does not exist error...

Comment: Have you replaced the backslashes with forward slashes? `//fab2crp-nas1/home22/kkang2/Profile/Desktop/FullData.csv`

Comment: My pleasure.  So there were two issues here: 1) the original path was incorrect and 2) the backslashes were acting as escape charaters.  Glad it's working for you.

Comment: cena: I reverted your last edit. Please don't apply solution to code in your question because then it no longer makes sense to others reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes are your issue - they are acting as escape characters.

#### Solution:

Use forward slashes like: `'C:/Users/kkang2/Desktop/FullData.csv'`

#### Benefit:

Using forward slashes as above carries a benefit over double backslashes as this method is **portable for both Win and *nix environments**, when using relative paths.

Comment: now it says" file does not exist error" when i have already saved my csv file on my desktop...

Comment: it says name "os is not defined"

Comment: it says false..which means it does not exist?

Comment: But why is this so ? I have my csv file save on my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

rewrite the path with two slashes

'C:\\Users\\kkang2\\Desktop\\FullData.csv'

Comment: @ Никита Колесников what do you mean by 2 slashes?

Comment: back double slash,  example - "\\path"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Use 'r' before providing path to the pd.read_csv method.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/kkang2/Desktop/FullData.csv')
```

'r' stands for 'raw'.
Please look over the internet if you are more interested.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using the `os` package

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

dirname = 'C:\Users\kkang2\Desktop'
filename = 'FullData.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
```

With `os` even the backslash works.